# Automatic generate target From Source List Make File

Tags: makefile

I have this directory structure.

```
app/
   src
   include
   lib/
       src
   maincode/
           main.cc
           Makefile
```

I want to generate automatic target from the source list in makefile. So I don't have to write rule for each file.

Example

```
source=\
        ../src/a.cpp
        ../src/ab.cpp
        ../lib/src/b.cpp
```

I want to write rule like

```
%.o:%.cpp
```

so that I don't have to repeat rule for each file. 
How I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit: the find command should be inside a shell variable

If you are using Linux, I think you can use:

```
SOURCES=$(shell find . -name *.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o)

%.o: %.cpp
    <command to compile>
```

Comment: I am using this type 
SOURCEFILE= \
 $(SRC_DIR)/vinit.cc \
 $(SRC_DIR)/vout.cc \

OBJECTS=$(SOURCEFILE:%.cc=%.o) 
but it is not working fine

Comment: I am not getting any error . 
but target is not getting called
%.o: %.cc
@echo "here"
it is not getting called

Answer (score 3):

I like Sagar's answer, though it took me a bit to figure out I what I wanted for an additional rule to cause creation of the objects:

```
    SOURCES=$(shell find . -name *.cpp)
    OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o)

    all: $(OBJECTS)

    %.o: %.cpp
         <command to compile dependencies $< into target $@ >  $< -o  $@
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CPP        = g++
CPPFLAGS   = -Wall -pedantic -O2 -g -c

SOURCES    := ${wildcard *.cpp}
OBJECTS    := ${SOURCES:.cpp=.o}

.PHONY:    all clean

.SUFFIXES: .cpp .o

all:       main

main:      $(OBJECTS)

.cpp.o:
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    -rm -fv *.o
```

For more info see [the man](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Function)

Comment: Convention says all instances of `CPP` here should be replaced with `CXX`. This is because `CPP` in a makefile actually usually means `C` `P`re`P`rocessor, not C++. `CXX` is taken to mean C++. The flags shown here in `CPPFLAGS` are not for the preprocessor but for the compiler itself. Of course, it doesn't actually matter what you call your variables - you could call them `BERT` and `ERNIE` - but conventions are only useful if people follow them!